How do I authenticate keycloak users on an ubuntu 22.04?
I am using an ubuntu 22.04 server with one admin account. On this Server is a Keycloak instance running. This Keycloak is connected to an LDAP in which multiple users are stored.
I now want to configure the server and Keycloak in a way that all Keycloak users that are added to the group "ubuntu_admins" can authenticate to the ubuntu admin account using their Keycloak (LDAP) credentials.
Till now I completed the steps described by: https://github.com/kha7iq/kc-ssh-pam
Unfortunately there isnt described how the Keycloak users are linked to the authentication process.
